# Facebook Share Issue for New AppId

Tags: facebook

I have implemented faceBook share.My code is working is working well for older faceBook AppId. When i created a new faceBook id in my account,sharing works in my account.If i login with another user account i am getting authorization error.Please help.
My code is

```
-(void)Share
{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Posting..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (!appDelegate.session)
    {
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc]initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",nil]];
        [self FBShare];
    }
    else
    {
        [self FBShare];
    }
}
-(void)FBShare
{

    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"publish_actions", nil];
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {

                                             [self postMessage];
                                         }];
    }else
        if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)[self postMessage];
}
-(void)postMessage
{


    NSMutableDictionary *parameters=
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[Hey %@",_barCode],@"name",
     _barImage,@"picture",
     @"image/jpeg",@"content_type"
     ,nil];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:parameters HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {
           NSLog(@"Posted");

        }

        else
        {

           NSLog(@"Error %@",error);

    }];
}
```

My error  response is

```
 Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x8ed73f0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 200;
        message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 403;
headers =     (
            {
        name = Expires;
        value = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
    },
            {
        name = "Cache-Control";
        value = "no-store";
    },
            {
        name = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
        value = "*";
    },
            {
        name = Pragma;
        value = "no-cache";
    },
            {
        name = "Content-Type";
        value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
    },
            {
        name = "WWW-Authenticate";
        value = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"insufficient_scope\" \"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action\"";
    }
);
```

}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: 2014-08-30 12:08:26 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-07-02 05:19:03 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "public_profile",
    email,
    "contact_email"
)>}

Comment: publish_stream have been deprecated for years. Use publish_actions instead

Comment: I don' know why everyone posts code with `publish_stream`...I think Facebook should definitely update the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your facebook AppId public..!!